# R - using map to apply a list function to dataframe column and create new columns with elements of the list

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I have a dataframe with and id column and an eats column, and a separate food list. I want to process the dataframe so that a column is added for each food in the food list which is populated with 1 if the food is present in eats and 0 otherwise.

```
txt <- tibble(id = c(1, 2, 3),
          eats = c("apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar",
                   "oats, banana, sugar",
                   "chocolate, milk, sugar"))

food_list <- c("apple", "oats", "chocolate")

for (i in food_list){
  print(i)
  txt <- txt %>% 
    mutate(!!i := if_else(stringr::str_detect(eats, i), 1, 0))
}
```

I could do this using a for loop but struggling to do it without a loop. I Will be very grateful if someone can point me to how this can be done without using for loops and instead using the purrr library map functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cbind` and `str_detect` , with `map_df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

cbind(txt, map_dfc(food_list, ~+str_detect(txt$eats, .x))%>%set_names(food_list))

  id                             eats apple oats chocolate
1  1 apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar     1    1         0
2  2              oats, banana, sugar     0    1         0
3  3           chocolate, milk, sugar     0    0         1
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `map` as

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
txt <- map_dfc(food_list, ~ txt %>%
      transmute(!! .x := +(stringr::str_detect(eats, .x)))) %>% 
    bind_cols(txt, .)
```

-output

```
txt
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id eats                             apple  oats chocolate
  <dbl> <chr>                            <int> <int>     <int>
1     1 apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar     1     1         0
2     2 oats, banana, sugar                  0     1         0
3     3 chocolate, milk, sugar               0     0         1
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done in on-liner

```
txt[food_list] <- +(sapply(food_list, grepl, x = txt$eats))
```

Comment: Ohh I just noticed that my answer is nearly similar to yours, but believe me I didn't copy the idea.  +1 already :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

txt %>%
  separate_rows(eats, sep = ", ") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ext = match(eats, food_list)) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = eats, values_from = ext, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>%
  right_join(txt, by = "id") %>%
  relocate(id, eats)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id eats                             apple  oats chocolate
  <dbl> <chr>                            <int> <int>     <int>
1     1 apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar     1     1         0
2     2 oats, banana, sugar                  0     1         0
3     3 chocolate, milk, sugar               0     0         1
```

Comment: Quite an adventure, going through pretty much the whole tidyverse to get the answer!

Comment: Yes it's more `tidyr`, `dplyr` and a little bit of base R :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use base R's `Reduce` like this

```
Reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[[b]] <- +(grepl(b, a[["eats"]]))
  a
}, init = txt, food_list)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id eats                             apple  oats chocolate
  <dbl> <chr>                            <int> <int>     <int>
1     1 apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar     1     1         0
2     2 oats, banana, sugar                  0     1         0
3     3 chocolate, milk, sugar               0     0         1
```

---

You may also use `purrr::reduce` similarly, where you can use (i) walrus operator and (ii) bang bang operators, instead of subsetting

```r
library(tidyverse)
txt <- tibble(id = c(1, 2, 3),
              eats = c("apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar",
                       "oats, banana, sugar",
                       "chocolate, milk, sugar"))

food_list <- c("apple", "oats", "chocolate")

reduce(food_list, .init = txt, ~ .x %>% 
         mutate(!!.y := +str_detect(eats, .y))
         )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id eats                             apple  oats chocolate
#>   <dbl> <chr>                            <int> <int>     <int>
#> 1     1 apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar     1     1         0
#> 2     2 oats, banana, sugar                  0     1         0
#> 3     3 chocolate, milk, sugar               0     0         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Add word boundaries (`\\b`) to the values in `food_list` so that words are matched completely.

For example, see the difference in outputs in the following case -

```
library(stringr)
x <- c('apple', 'pineapple')

str_detect(x, 'apple')
#[1] TRUE TRUE

str_detect(x, '\\bapple\\b')
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

The same goes for `grepl` in base R -

```
food_list <- c("apple", "oats", "chocolate")
food_pat <- sprintf('\\b%s\\b', food_list)
txt[food_list] <- lapply(food_pat, function(x) as.integer(grepl(x, txt$eats)))
txt

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     id eats                             apple  oats chocolate
#  <dbl> <chr>                            <int> <int>     <int>
#1     1 apple, oats, banana, milk, sugar     1     1         0
#2     2 oats, banana, sugar                  0     1         0
#3     3 chocolate, milk, sugar               0     0         1
```